# Find the limit of $x \ln[\ln(x^{-2})]$ as $x$ tends to $0$

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms

$$\lim_{x\to 0}x \ln\left( \ln\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)$$

What's the proper way to evaluate the limit of such a function ?

Comment: simplify $$\ln\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ to $$-2\ln|x|$$

Comment: One time  l'hopital, will do. For that write $x=1/(1/x)$.

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to 0}x \log\log x^{-2} = \lim_{y\to 0^+} \sqrt{y} \log\log\frac{1}{y} = \lim_{z\to +\infty}\frac{\log\log z}{\sqrt{z}}=0.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One time l'Hopital (H):
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}x\ln\left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \right)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(-\ln(x^2))}{1/x}\stackrel{H}{=}\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-2x}{\ln(x^2)}
\end{align}
Now you can finish right?

Comment: ok now I understand it was simply a matter of obtaining an indeterminate form to use l'Hopital's rule... the "double ln" kinda confused me, never encountered that before. thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

then you will have $$\lim_{x \to 0}x\ln(-2\ln|x|)=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\frac1{x^2}=e^{2y}$ with $y\to +\infty$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}x \ln\left( \ln\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)=\lim_{y\to +\infty}\frac1{e^y} \ln(2y)=\lim_{y\to +\infty}\frac{2y}{e^y} \frac{\ln(2y)}{2y}=0$$